# ¿Cómo aplico la función "while" en este caso?

Tags: python

Se me pide que calcule el valor de los productos que el cliente vaya agregando, esto con un bucle `while`, mi código es el siguiente:

```
NOMBRE_CLIENTE=input ("CLIENTE : ")
NOMBRE_CLIENTE=input ("CLIENTE : ")
    
PRODUCTO=int(input ("Valor : "))
X=PRODUCTO
while X>0:         
    print (PRODUCTO=int(input ("Valor : ")))
```

Comment: chesco, bienvenido a S.O. en español...  Se que eres nuevo en la comunidad, y eso se refleja en la calidad de la pregunta. Primero te recomiendo que te des un [tour] para conocer y saber como funciona el sitio. Luego, ve a [ask] para que luego puedas editar y mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Créeme, te ayudara a llegar a muchísimas mas personas y por ende vas a tener una mayor posibilidad de que tu pregunta sea respondida satisfactoriamente. Por ultimo: muéstranos que has intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: por favor pon lo que has intentado, asi sabremos que en realidad quieres aprender y que no solo quieres que resuelvan tu tarea. De esa forma otras personas podrán aprender

Comment: Hiciste bien en agregar lo que intentaste c: Pero podrías ponerlo en forma de texto por favor? O sea pega el código en la pregunta y dale formato seleccionándo todo el código y presionando las {} que están arriba de la caja de texto. Aquí tienes un enlace que explica por que te pido esto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2869#2869

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como antes solo dejaste el enunciado de tu problema elabore una explicación, pero ahora que la editaste te podre ayudar con tu problema, la explicación nunca esta de mas, aparte tendrás conceptos mas claros.

## Ciclo `While`

La sintaxis es la siguiente `while <condición>`, este ciclo ejecutara un bloque de código **mientras** se cumpla la condición especificada. Si tu creas variables dentro de este bloque las variables siempre sobrescribirán su valor si el bucle se repite mas de una vez. La condición se evaluara en cada iteración, por lo que si la condición en un momento deja de cumplirse el bucle se detendrá y el programa seguirá su ejecución. Ejemplo:

```py
num = 0
while num < 5: #mientras num sea menor que 5
    num +=1 #sumamos 1 a la variable
print(num) #4
#el bucle se detendra cuando num sea 4 ya que 5 no es menor que 5
```

Pero que pasa si queremos detener el bucle sin que se cumpla la condición?, ¿se puede?, la respuesta es **Sí**, para eso hacemos uso de algunas palabras reservadas de python.

### Sentencias

Existen las siguientes palabras reservadas o sentencias para el ciclo `while`.

- `break`: Termina el bucle.
- `continue`: Vuelve al inicio del bucle, omite el código que hay debajo de el.

También se puede considerar a `pass` aunque su uso es global (se puede usar en cualquier parte) esto le indica al código que simplemente siga.

**Ejemplos**

```py
#ejemplo con break
num = 0
while True: #siempre se ejecutara
    if num >= 8: #verificamos si en mayor o igual a 8
        break #terminamos el ciclo
    num += 1#sumamos 1
    print(num) #imprimimos el numero

#esto nos imprimira los numeros del 1 al 8

#ejemplo con continue

num = 0

#mientras que num-1 sea menor que 10
while num -1 < 10:
    if num%2 == 0: #si el numero es par lo "omitimos"
        num +=1 #sumamos 1
        continue #volvemos al inicio
        print("el numero es par") #esto se omitira
    else: #si la condicion anterioir no se cumple
      print(f"el numero {num} es impar")
      num += 1 #sumamos 1 de lo contrario se quedara imprimiendo siempre
```

El bucle `while` acepta un bloque `else` que se ejecutara uando la condicion no se cumpla, por ejemplo si le pedimos al usuario que ingrese un numero menor de 5 y el usuario ingresa 6, se ejecutara el bloque `else`, por lo que sé Python es el único lenguaje que admite esa sintaxis.
Dicho todo eso ahora podemos resolver tu problema.

## Tu código

Te hace falta una variable que sea una lista para almacenar los datos que ingrese el usuario, y aremos uso del método `append()` para agregar elementos a una lista, también la ultima linea esta mal, Python no admite ese tipo de sintaxis. Ahora vamos a mejorarlo.

```py
nombre_cliente =input ("Por favor ingrese el nombre del cliente : ")

price_products = []
producto = 1 #inicializamos con el valor de 1 para que la condicion se cumpla
#verificamos si el valor no es 0
while producto !=0:
    producto = int(input("Valor del producto: "))#pedimos el valor
    if producto !=0:#si es diferente de 0 agregamso
        price_products.append(producto)#agregamos a la lista

else: #si ingresa 0 le damos los detalles
    print(f"la lista de precios de productos del cliente {nombre_cliente} es \n{str(price_products)}")
    total = sum(price_products)
    print(f"compraste {len(price_products)}\ntotal = {total}")
```

El código lo puedes simplificar con los conceptos que explique anteriormente y utilizando el [operador morsa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453785/c%c3%b3mo-se-utiliza-el-operador-morsa) y moviendo algunas líneas de código, para evitar redundancia, pero eso te lo dejo a ti para que investigues y aprendas algo mas :)