# pasar este codigo a lista por compresion

Tags: python

```py
N = int(input("Ingrese N:"))
lista = []
for i in range(N):
    a = input("Nombre: ")
    if a.startswith("A") == True or a.startswith("E") == True or a.startswith("e") == True or a.startswith("a") == True:
        lista.append(a)
print("Nombres:", lista)
```

Comment: y que has intentado?

Comment: lista=[ a for i in range(int(input("Ingrese un valor N: "))) (a=(input()).lower()) if  a.startswith("a")==True or  a.startswith("e") ]

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/468534/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo el código de los comentarios

Comment: ¿Tendrías la gentileza de explicar en breves palabras cual es el resultado que esperas obtener?

Answer (score 0):

Pides una cosa complicada y que no he sido de capaz de escribir nada más limpio que esto:

```py
lista = [nombre
         for nombre in (input("Nombre: ") for _ in range(int(input("Ingrese N:"))))
         if any(nombre.startswith(letra) for letra in "AEae")]
```

El motivo por el que hay que escribirlo de una forma tan extraña es que la condición se comprueba antes que la evaluación del elemento que se añadirá a la lista.
Por lo tanto construimos un iterable que nos pedirá `N` nombres.
Cada vez que reciba un nombre comprobará si es un nombre válido para añadirlo en la lista.

El código tal y como está escrito comprobará la validez de cada nombre justo después de introducirlo.
Esto es porque uso un generador en vez de una lista.
Aunque esto no cambia nada el resultado del código.

En la última línea he escrito de manera más corta tu comprobación de la inicial.
Tomo las 4 letras que te interesan `AEae` y compruebo si alguna de ellas es la inicial de `name`.

---

No está relacionado con tu pregunta, pero en general si quieres comprobar que empiece por *a* o *e* sin que sea sensible a mayúsculas harías algo como `name.lower().startswith(letter) for letter in "ae"`.
Es decir, conviertes tu string a minúsculas y comparas sólo con las letras que te interesan.

---

Mi consejo es que escribas esta list comprehension de la siguiente forma

```
# Generador que me irá pidiendo los nombres
todos_los_nombres = (input("Nombre: ") for _ in range(N))
# Lista que filtra los elementos de todos_los_nombres
nombres_validos = [nombre in todos_los_nombres
                   if any(nombre.startswith(letra) for letra in "AEae")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion podria ser utilizar el [operador morsa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/453785/c%C3%B3mo-se-utiliza-el-operador-morsa)(introducido en python 3.8) que te permite asignar variables en expresiones

```py
lista=[nombre for _ in range(int(input("Nombre N"))) if (nombre:=input("Nombre"))[0].lower() in "ae"]
print("Nombres: ",lista)
```

Lo que permite este codigo es al mismo tiempo que comprobas en caso de que la comprobacion sea verdadera retornarla a la variable nombre